# Websocket Handshake Immediately closes only in IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, websocket

I have a simple website with a login form using Websockets .Although it works fine with Firefox and Chrome, no connection is established and thus no login using IE 10 or 11. I used Fiddler and noticed that the result in successful connections is 101(that is in Chrome and Firefox),while in IE it is 200. Furthermore,the following message :

SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 200, OK

appears in IE console. Any ideas about what is wrong?

Comment: Well, it is difficult to say... but could it be that the server is showing an error page and that is why you see the HTTP 200? What server are you connecting too? do you see anything in the server logs?

Answer (score 0):

This has been a while, but anyway I suppose it might help someone else. I have ran into this. The problem was incorrect websocket servlet definition in web.xml. You might also have to add the said servlet in the struts.xml exclude patterns.